# gitignore files have been deleted locally

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out what the best approach is for my situation. I had removed everything from my repository and recommitted in order for my gitignore files to work. It did, however, I switched to another branch that is still tracking everything, then checked out the original branch, and now those files are not there.

From what I understand this is the correct git behaviour, but I was wondering how I could stop tracking these core files while keeping them locally in order for my site to function?

Should I merge branch branch A (no core files) with branch B (core files), then clear the repository and recommit?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is many fold. First, when you want to drop files to be tracked further on a branch, but keep the files themselves you will use

```
git rm --cached FILE
// possibly edit .gitignore here and `git add .gitignore`
git commit -m "removed the file FILE"
```

On the other hand, it seems that you want this for a checkout procedure for the contents of web site or something similar.

As you want to merge `A` and `B`,it seems you want this rule (removing FILE from the index) for all branches. This can be done with

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatched HEAD -- FILE'
```

. Be careful to have the `FILE`s in your work tree or have a backup outside of your repository, as the HEAD you fire this command on, will loose all ideas of what these files ever had been, so you cannot check them out again from the history! You will either need them in your work tree or have a backup **before** you filter your history.

I dislike the idea, for some reasons, to have the repository that near to a working directory that might contain a mix of tracked files, additional files or even files from other repositories, that track a distinct set of files.

For such a use case it is often useful to use a second --work-tree for your repository

```
git --work-tree=WHERE_YOU_PUBLISH_YOUR_FILES checkout HEAD -- .
```

to checkout the tracked files from HEAD to your `htdocs` or whatever. Inside of `WHERE_YOU_PUBLISH_YOUR_FILES` you can put any other files, without touching the repository.

You can check differences of the tracked files, of a repository, against the work tree with

```
git --work-tree=WHERE_YOU_PUBLISH_YOUR_FILES diff
```

. You can even check in the files from `WHERE_YOU_PUBLISH_YOUR_FILES` into the repository

```
git --work-tree=WHERE_YOU_PUBLISH_YOUR_FILES add -u
```

To simplify this operation I often use global aliases.

```
git config --global alias.public '!git --work-tree $(git config --get public.path)'
git config public.path /var/www/localhost/htdocs
```

Now you can use

```
git public status -s -uno
```

or similar commands.

Comment: I actually did do git rm --cached but I think when I switched branches and then went back... Could that have been the issue? In any case, I want to merge these two branches together, get the gitignore files back, then stop tracking those git ignore files again.

Comment: The merge does not help, it will just add the rm change onto B too. You can `git checkout B -- COREFILES; git reset HEAD` in branch A to get the removed files again.

Comment: if I checkout b corefiles, how can I then checkout branch A to do the git reset?

Comment: If you `git checkout B -- COREFILES` and you where on branch `A` before, then you are still on branch `A`, with the `COREFILES` from `B` added to `A`, but not commited. When you then reset the COREFILES, they are untracked in A but the files are in the work tree, as requested.